# integrate $\int e^{\sqrt{x}}dx$

Tags: integration

> $$\int e^{\sqrt{x}}dx$$

$t=\sqrt{x}$

$dt=\dfrac{dx}{2\sqrt{x}}\Rightarrow dx=2\sqrt{x}\,dt\Rightarrow dx=2t\,dt$

$$\int e^{\sqrt{x}} \, dx=2\int e^t t\,dt$$

$u=t\Rightarrow u'=1$

$v'=e^t\Rightarrow v=e^t$

$$2\int e^t t \, dt=te^t-\int e^t \, dt=te^t-e^t+c$$

So the answer is $\sqrt{x}e^{\sqrt{x}}-e^{\sqrt{x}}+c$?

Comment: What happens when you differentiate your answer? You're basically correct. Just missing a factor of 2 in the last line,

Comment: On differentiating you won't get $e^{\sqrt{x}}$

Comment: You forgot about the "2" on the left hand side of the third display...

Comment: After you say $t=\sqrt x$, it's a bit quicker to say $t^2 = x$ and then differentiate both sides to get $2t\,dt = dx$. $\qquad$

Comment: I got to $2\int e^{t}dt=te^{t}-e^{t}+c$ isn't it an equally? why do I need to factor the left side in 2 also?

Comment: I seem to understand it is just like $3\int x=3\frac{x^2}{2}$ and not $3\int x=\frac{x^2}{2}$

Answer (score 1):

$$\int\exp[\sqrt{x}]\space\text{d}x=$$

---

Substitute $u=\sqrt{x}$ and $\text{d}u=\frac{1}{\sqrt{x}}\space\text{d}x$:

---

$$2\int u\exp[u]\space\text{d}u=$$

---

Using integration by parts:

$$\int q\space\text{d}z=qz-\int z\space\text{d}q$$

Where $q=u,\text{d}q=\text{d}u,z=e^u,\text{d}z=e^u\space\text{d}u$:

---

$$2ue^u-2\int\exp[u]\space\text{d}u=2ue^u-2e^u+\text{C}=$$
$$2\sqrt{x}e^{\sqrt{x}}-2e^{\sqrt{x}}+\text{C}=2e^{\sqrt{x}}\left(\sqrt{x}-1\right)+\text{C}$$